# HTML form with 2 submit buttons

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am having a HTML form with 2 submit buttons. One is for submitting the form and other one is for executing a Java Script function. When I click the button to execute the Java script function it tries to submit the form. How can I handle this situation. That is I want the form to be submitted when the submit button is clicked and Java script function to run when the other button is clicked.

Comment: Call JavaScript function on button click, submit form at the end of the JavaScript function.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: By default, button elements in forms are submit buttons. Use `type="button"` or use an input with `type="button"` and it will not submit the form.

Comment: i used button type = "button", then it worked. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using a `type="submit"` button for the javascript action?

Instead use a `<button onclick="myFunction()">Button Text</button>`

If you are resetting the form you could use `type="reset"`

Comment: Almost there. By default, button elements in forms are type submit, the OP needs to use type button.

Comment: i used button type = "button", then it worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your "JavaScript" submit button, return false after executing your code, that should prevent it from submitting the form.